# pandas groupby with ignore some rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have such DataFrame

```
            W2     N      V1     V2

            ba     EX     62069  30014
            ba     ADV    12325  8218 
            ba     X      23     22 
            b      X      164831 39425 
            b      PRT    41543  16708
```

I need groupby W2 with same values in one row summing V1, V2 values. This row should be where V1==max.
I do it:

```
   df_4=df_2.sort_values(['W2','V1'],ascending=[True, False]).drop_duplicates(['W2'])
   df_3= df_2.groupby(['W2'],as_index=False).sum()
```

but when i search max i need ignore row where N==EX(only max, sum should include V1 and V2 of this rows).
So result should be:

```
        W2     N      V1     V2

        ba     ADV    74417  38254
        b      X      206374 56133
```

I hope i can do it with pandas. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think need first filter out rows by [`query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) or [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and add [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with select `N` column only for [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html), last add [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) if need change final order by `df_2`:

```
s = (df_2.query('N != "EX"')
         .sort_values(['W2','V1'],ascending=[True, False])
         .drop_duplicates(['W2'])
         .set_index('W2')['N'])
```

---

```
s = (df_2[df_2['N'] != "EX"]
        .sort_values(['W2','V1'],ascending=[True, False])
        .drop_duplicates(['W2'])
        .set_index('W2')['N'])
print (s)
W2
b       X
ba    ADV
Name: N, dtype: object

df_3 = df_2.groupby('W2', as_index=False, sort=False).sum()
df_3['N'] = df_3['W2'].map(s)
df_3 = df_3.reindex(columns=df_2.columns)
print (df_3)
   W2    N      V1     V2
0  ba  ADV   74417  38254
1   b    X  206374  56133
```